# Getting error when trying to git push to remote branch (Heroku)

Tags: heroku, github, git-push

Hi I tried to push my local changes to heroku production but I am getting the following error

```
Zhens-MacBook-Pro:Dailymuses-Server-Side zaikshev88$ git push heroku-production master:master
To git@heroku.com:dailymuses.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dailymuses.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

The issue here is that when I tried to do a git pull, I was told that everything is up to date

```
Zhens-MacBook-Pro:Dailymuses-Server-Side zaikshev88$ git pull origin master
From github.com:mingyeow/Dailymuses-Server-Side
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

What is the issue here and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 10):

Your `push` command is to remote `heroku-production` but your `pull` command is to `origin`. The `non-fast-foward` message means the history in your current repo differs from the Heroku remote; likely someone has pushed a branch with some merges or rebases.

I implore you to not use Heroku as the authoritative git remote. Assuming you are not, you can force push over the Heroku master branch to resolve this.

```
git push -f heroku-production master:master
```